# How to Convert Dict to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
number_pad = {"b":2,"a":2,"c":2,"x":4,"y":4,"z":4}
```

My print statement is

```
print(get_number,('00bx'))
```

How to get the output like this: 0024.

I tried this:

```
get_number = ""
for key,val in num_pad.items():
        get_number =  get_phone_number + str(val)
```

Is there anyway can relate letters to numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict.get(...)` for your task:

```
number_pad = {"b":2,"a":2,"c":2,"x":4,"y":4,"z":4}

text = '00bx'
re_text = ""
for t in text:
    re_text += str(number_pad.get(t, t))
print(re_text) # output: 0024
```

Or you can condense it to this:

```
re_text = "".join(str(number_pad.get(t, t)) for t in text)
print(re_text) # output: 0024
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this essentially what you are after?

```
str(number_pad['b']) + str(number_pad['x'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the *map* function with a lambda expression.

```
number_pad = {'b': 2, 'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'x': 4, 'y': 4, 'z': 4}
print(''.join(map(lambda c: str(number_pad[c]) if c in number_pad.keys() else c, '00bx')))
```